# Creating functions for each variadic template type

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, conversion-operator

I have several functions for a class which do the exact same thing but with a different type.

```
class ExampleWrapper
{
public:
    operator T1() { ... }
    operator T2() { ... }
    operator T3() { ... }
};
```

Is it possible to combine these into a single template parameter:

```
class ExampleWrapper : public Wrapper<T1, T2, T3>
{
   // does the same as above
};
```

Bonus: Do you think this that having these functions explicitly there (perhaps with a proper name) is more readable?

Edit: 
T1, T2, T3 are some types specified by some API.

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by "different type" in the question

Comment: Don't think so.  Where's the code to implement your `operator`s going to go?  Can't say I see the point, either.

Comment: A better way to do this may be to have some base type you can inherit from.

Comment: If the logic is the same for all, use a template? `template <typename T> operator T() { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we don't have reflection or `template for` yet, you can use variadic inheritance to compose a type with all the member function we need.

Let's start with the one type case:

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    operator T() { ... }
};
```

We can now inherit multiple times from this struct using pack expansion:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct WrapperVariadic : Wrapper<Ts>... {};
```

Then, inherit from that:

```
struct HaveManyWrappers : WrapperVariadic<T1, T2, T3> {
    // ...
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, just surprised that this is proper syntax.

Comment: @Yeladia yeah you'll really want to have `template for` and reflection for that kind of stuff, it will be much closer to normal code.